# Attachments to non-persisting record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

So I have a `items/new.html.erb` page that has a form for a new `Items` record.

Now the page has an image uploads section also, beside the new record form, where the user can upload multiple images. This UI design suggests that the user should be able to upload images, or attach images to the to-be-created record.

My current setup is when the user uploads an image in the page(this is handled via AJAX/rails UJS), the `id` of the uploaded image/images will be added in a hidden field in the new `Item` form. Then only when the main form is submitted will the images be attached to the newly created `Item` resource. I feel that this is an unusual way of handling this issue and that there is a more easy, clear, Rails way for this.

I call the images like this:

```
item.images
```

The page also allows that the user be able to sort or update the order of the Image attachments, but this I think is a topic that should be in another discussion.

How do you handle this, the first issue, properly and clearly in Rails?

Answer (score 2):

### Nested attributes

Rails has a built in mechanism called [`accepts_nested_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). Which lets you create nested records in the same request:

```
class Item
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end

class Image
  belongs_to :item
  has_one_attached :file
end
```

This will let you create an item and images with:

```
Item.create(name: 'Foo', image_attributes: [{ file: 'foo.jpg'}, { file: 'bar.jpg'}])
```

ActiveRecord will handle inserting the records in the correct order.

This allows you to have a non-nullable foreign key (`item_id`) and avoid orphaned records which is a very real problem with your solution. [Referential integrity](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/referential-integrity-with-foreign-keys) should be pretty high on your list of priorities.

This is used in the model together with [`fields_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) in the view (the form).

```
<%= form_with(model: @item) do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for(:images) do |image_fields| %>
    <%= image_fields.file_field :file %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And by passing an array of keys in the strong parameters:

```
params.require(:item).permit(:name, image_attributes: [:file])
```

### ActiveStorage's `has_many_attached`

ActiveStorage also lets you setup a one to many assocation without a model by using `has_many_attached`. The attachements are stored in the `active_storage_attachments` table. However there is no way as far as I know of attaching additional metadata (such as the ordering) to the attachements.

Comment: Hi max thank for this. This is a very nice and detailed answer, however I am looking for one that would fit the question more. Nesting the image fields into the parent's form would mean creating the parent and the images through a single request, I have done this. A scenario where images being created first on a separate request is what I am looking for.